# Build fails at the code for initialising Sentry's Vuejs (with Typescript) Integration

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sentry

When I run the build for my (vue-cli-3 based) Vuejs project via gitlab-runner on my local, it breaks with the following error:

```
98% after emitting CopyPlugin ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors ...
Property 'util' is missing in type 'VueConstructor<Vue>' but required in type 'VueInstance'.

    75 |   integrations: [
    76 |     Integrations.Vue({
  > 77 |       Vue,
       |       ^
    78 |       attachProps: true,
    79 |     })
```

I have imported Vue, Sentry and Sentry Integrations at the top of the same file as follows:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';
import * as Integrations from '@sentry/integrations';
```

What does the error mean and how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same issue today after a `yarn upgrade`.

After some searching this appears to be a bug in the integrations part of Sentry.
You can find more information about this here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2633

It also includes a workaround to get around this issue until a fix is released.

Comment: The release containing this fix is out https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/releases/tag/5.17.0. So, now just upgrade sentry versions and the problem will be fixed. Many thanks @adam!